# What's the difference between a 'task' and a 'quest'?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I don't quite get the difference, some NPCs give quests, but others give tasks?

[image]

Comment: I believe it's that a task requires a single completion condition, where as a quest will be multi-part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks are smaller/shorter quests that generally have 3 or fewer stages and have little to no effect on your party or on any major happenings in the game.

Comment: Gotcha. At some point I'd like something more solid here, but I'll accept this for now. Thank you.

Comment: If I find more specific parameters for task vs. quest I will update the answer.